# Max and min of $f(x,y)$ on $C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\ge 0,y\ge 0\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)={1 \over |x|}{\int_{0}^{xy} {{e^t-1}\over {t}}dt}$ for $x\ne0$ and null for $x=0$.

The function is null over axis and positive in the first quadrant.

How can I prove if there is a maximum on $C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\ge 0,y\ge 0\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that $e^t\geq 1+ t$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$, hence for $(x,y)\in C$ and $x>0$,
$$f(x,y)={1 \over |x|}{\int_{0}^{xy} {{e^t-1}\over {t}}dt}\geq {1 \over x}\int_{0}^{xy}dt=y.$$
Does $f$ has a global maximum over $C$?

Comment: it's unlimited superior ($+\infty$)

Comment: Yes, you are correct!